# Animation doesn't start in Safari, via code

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I have this animation

```
@keyframes scroll {
 0% {
  top: 100%;
 }
 100% {
  top: -170%;
 }
}
```

used by an element

```
#titlecontent {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 animation: scroll 150s linear 1s;
 color:#3998AC;
}
```

everything works fine with any browser including Safari (both Windows Safari and iPad Safari).
But if I comment the keyframes part and insert it via jquery like this

```
$("#animazione").html("<style>@keyframes scroll {0% {top: 100%;} 100% {top: -170%;}}</style>");
```

it doesn't work anymore in Safari. If I inspect the code I can see that the text has been properly inserted in the DOM but it does nothing. Only in Safari.
What could I do?

I am here adding more information also to format the code I did following Rory's advice.

I now have

```
 #titlecontent { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%; color:#3998AC; 
  } 
 .start{ 
  animation: scroll 150s linear 1s; 
}
```

I have the keyframes animation and then associated with a click function I do:

```
$("#titlecontent").addClass( "start" );
```

With firefox and Chrome this is fine but nothing with Safari

Comment: It's very odd that you want to add a keyframes animation that way. If you're trying to dynamically start the effect on an element, put the `animation` rule on a CSS class, then add that class to the element via JS

Comment: Still no success

Comment: Sorry, I posted the commenti without finishing it

So now I have this
     #titlecontent {
     position: absolute;
    top: 100%;

    color:#3998AC;
   }
   .start{
     animation: scroll 150s linear 1s;
    }

Comment: OMG I cannot even answer properly

So now I have this 

    #titlecontent { position: absolute; top: 100%; color:#3998AC; } 
    .start{ animation: scroll 150s linear 1s; }

I have the keyframes animation and then associated with a click function I do:

  $("#titlecontent").addClass( "start" );

With firefox and Chrome this is fine but nothing with Safari. I cannot understand the issue. I am sorry I am unable to format properly this reply.